# What is preferred: `toBe(null)` or `toEqual(null)`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, null, jestjs

I know the difference between `toBe` and `toEqual`. I also know that `toBe(null)` and `toEqual(null)` will always return the same value, no matter on which node you call them.

What I would like to know is if there is a **preferred** or **recommended** way to check for `null`. Or if there is just no recommendation in that regard, and using the one or the other depends just on the team (or even on the developer).

Thank you very much for *any* insight that you can provide! :)

EDIT: I have just seen that there is also `toBeNull()`. Is that preferred, maybe, or it just does not matter which one you use?

Comment: asserts are always meant to be easy to read. go for what you find more readable.

Comment: The whole point of unit testing (other than testing your code) is for anyone who comes and looks are your tests to **immediately** understand what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you @NaeemShaikh and @kemicofa! Shall I understand that there is no preferred option in the community? I am very new to these topics, hence my interest!

Comment: This is a matter of preference here. As a rule of thumb, I use toEquals only when deep comparison is involved, otherwise strict comparison is used. This gives a clear signal how the test works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no practical difference between them, they behave similarly with `null`.

`toBe` provides `===` comparison (more specifically, `Object.is`).

`toEqual` provides looser comparison that uses some magic. It isn't documented in detail. It uses `===` to compare primitives but there are exceptions when objects are involved, e.g. `expect(false).toEqual(new Boolean(false))`. Even though it uses [`===` for `null`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/v23.6.0/packages/expect/src/jasmine_utils.js#L87-L89), it requires some expertise to deduce what `expect(someValue).toEqual(null)` assertion does.

`expect(someValue).toBe(null)` assertion unambiguously suggests that strict comparison is used, so does `expect(someValue).toBeNull()`.